# Multipart vs Json Batch processing

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata

It seems that OData has two ways of sending batch requests, one using [multipart](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part1-protocol.html#_Toc31359017) and one using [json](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.01/odata-json-format-v4.01.html#_Toc38457781).

Why would I choose one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft Graph API then only JSON batching is supported.

Resources:

[Combine multiple requests in one HTTP call using JSON batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0)